# What are the consequences of failing the Strength check to move in a Web spell?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

Regarding this part of the Web spell in D&D 3.5:

> Each round devoted to moving allows the creature to make a new Strength check or Escape Artist check. The creature moves 5 feet for each full 5 points by which the check result exceeds 10.

If the check happens to be less than 15, are there any adverse effects other than that you don't move at all that round?  Do you become re-webbed to the point of immobility, and have to spend an entire round breaking loose before you can move again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## There are no adverse consequences

There are two different states you can be in while affected by a *[web](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/web.htm)*:

> If the save fails, the creature is entangled and can’t move from its space, but can break loose by spending 1 round and making a DC 20 Strength check or a DC 25 Escape Artist check.

The initial Strength check or Escape Artist check is functionally a replacement for the Reflex save - if you succeed, you get out.

> Once loose (either by making the initial Reflex save or a later Strength check or Escape Artist check), a creature remains entangled, but may move through the web very slowly.

After you've broken out through any means (Reflex save, or later check) you are no longer subject to the initial part of the spell. There is no mechanic provided for returning to the initial part of the spell no matter how many checks you fail.

Comment: Well, no adverse consequence except from being slowed down, and therefore potentially not being able to participate to the fights where your companions are getting slaughtered since the group is cut in half... :)